# Specifying statement paper size

Tags: paper-size

I want to create a document that will be printed on statement paper (i.e. half of US letter paper – 8.5" x 5.5"). With metric sized papers it seems clear how to do this using `a5paper`. How do I do the same thing with statement paper?

Comment: This paper size is also known as "Organizer L" and "Half Letter". I know that I can use something like 

\usepackage[paperwidth=5.5in, paperheight=8.5in]{geometry} but is there a built in way to do this?

Comment: You should move this comment into the body of your posting. Incidentally, what's wrong with specifying the paper size with the `geometry` package?

Answer (score 3):

With the `memoir` class

```
\documentclass[statementpaper,...]{memoir}
```

will do it.